# Filter data inside modal div

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, modal-dialog, twig

I have a map with differents points. I want to display for each point onClick a specific data in a "modal" container. 
I can't do this in the twig file because I don't know which point will be selected. So I guess it is the job of Javascript and Ajax.

I can have the button id in js and ajax or symfony, but what to do next for filtering data ?

The only solution I reached is opening the data in a new windows.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at fancybox - http://fancyboxjs.com - you can easily display data from html, ajax or even iframe

Comment: Thank you ! You're right, it's simpler with fancybox :)